# How to display a menu based on another menu's submenu items (Joomla 2.5)

Tags: joomla2.5

This is probably really easy to do and I'm probably missing the wood for the trees but I'm trying to display a menu on a selection of pages which contains the sub menu items from the equivalent main menu item.

For example, the main menu has 'Products' (parent item) listed with 'Product 1', 'Product 2' and 'Product 3' as sub menu items (child items).  Is it possible (without creating duplicate articles) to create a submenu which only shows the child items but which links to the same articles as from the main menu?

I've read about using menu-alias but none of the documentation I've found gives a clear message on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Go to `Menus -> Menu Manager -> Add Menu`.

2) Add a new menu item in it, choose for type `Menu Item Alias` and on the right side under *Menu Item* choose which *Menu* you want it to be the copy of (not a real copy, but an alias).

3) Repeat 2) for all menu items you want to display

4) In `Module Manager`, add new `Menu` module, choose your newly created Menu, assign it to some position and publish.

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly what I was after and it was pretty simple in the end.  Thanks Marco, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

@Marko D's solution works well and can be customised to suit many variations.

There's another option in this case where you don't event need to create another menu or menu aliases.

1) In module manager, add a new menu module, name it, position it, apply it to the relevant pages, then **under Basic Options choose the main menu in question and a start level of 2** and publish

2) No number 2 ;)

It's always good to have more than 1 option!